# xargs: exec command with prompt

Tags: xargs

I'm trying to do the following with xargs

`pacman -Q | grep xf86-video | awk '{print $1}' | xargs pacman -R` to remove all xf86-video-* driver on my machine. To make the question more clear, here is the output of `pacman -Q | grep xf86-video | awk '{print $1}'`:

```
xf86-video-ark
xf86-video-ati
xf86-video-dummy
xf86-video-fbdev
xf86-video-glint
xf86-video-i128
xf86-video-intel
xf86-video-mach64
xf86-video-neomagic
xf86-video-nouveau
....
```

when I redirect the result to `xargs`, the output looks like this:

[image: xargs result]

The point is, the command which `xargs` is about to execute need user to do some **additional** input(as you can see it needs a Yes/No), but `xargs` **automatically** add a unknown symbol ***#***, and exit, which causes my purpose UNACHIEVED.

WHY `xargs` would do this or, what can I do to use `xargs` for command with prompt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
xargs -a <(pacman -Q | awk '/xf86-video/{print $1}') pacman -R
```

#### Explanation:

Without further arguments `xargs` does not work with interactive (command line) applications.

The reason for that is, that by default`xargs` gets its input from *stdin* but interactive applications also expect input from *stdin*. To prevent the applications from grabbing input that is intended for `xargs`, `xargs` redirects *stdin* from `/dev/null` for the applications it runs. This leads to the application just receiving an *EOF*. (Running just `pacman -R SOMEPACKAGE` and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> has the same effect).

To get `xargs` to work with interactive commands you have to use the `--arg-file=FILE` argument (short `-a FILE`). This tells `xargs` to get the arguments from `FILE`. This also leaves *stdin* unchanged.

So you could either put your package list into a temporary file

```
pacman -Q | awk '/xf86-video/{print $1}' > /tmp/packagelist
xargs -a /tmp/packagelist pacman -R
rm /tmp/packagelist
```

or you can use *zsh's* process substitution mechanism `<(list)`. When executing a line with `<(list)`, `<(list)` is replaced by a filename from where the output of `list` can be read.

```
xargs -a <(pacman -Q | awk '/xf86-video/{print $1}') pacman -R
```

---

The single **#** you get is not from `xargs` but from `zsh` itself. If the shell options `PROMPT_CR` and `PROMPT_SP` are set (which both are by default) `zsh` tries to preserve partial lines, that is lines that did not end with a newline. To signify that such a line has been preserved zsh prints an inverse+bold character at the end of that line, by default **%** for normal users and **#** for root.

Answer (score 3):

### You can eliminate the use of xargs with a single hyphen

> Additionally, if stdin is not from a terminal and a single hyphen (-) is passed as an argument, targets will be read from stdin.
> — https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html

```
pacman -Q | awk '/xf86-video/{print $1}' | pacman -R -
```

### You *can* use xargs, though ...

If you wish to use xargs, use it's `-o`, `--open-tty` option:

> `--open-tty`
> `-o`
> Reopen stdin as `/dev/tty` in the child process before executing the command, thus allowing that command to be associated to the terminal while `xargs` reads from a different stream, e.g. from a pipe. This is useful if you want `xargs` to run an interactive application.
>
> ```
>  grep -lz PATTERN * | xargs -0o vi  ①
> ```
>
> — https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html

① <sub>That should be an uppercase Z grep option [(bug filed)](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?61341).</sub>

For your particular case:

```
pacman -Q | awk '/xf86-video/{print $1}' | xargs -o pacman -R
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run pacman the second time with the `--noconfirm` option:

```
pacman -Q | grep xf86-video | awk '{print $1}' | xargs pacman -R --noconfirm
```

This will disable 'are you sure' messages, and do things without requiring input.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this option of  `--noconfirm` and already fixed the problem, but what I really want to know is what to **#** means.

Comment: Probably, the '#' is just your console displaying an end-of-file character, `x0`.

Comment: Then, why `xargs` would pass such a `x0` to the prompt?

Comment: it's possible awk did. But the `#` character in the console is usually what it displays when it's trying to display a non-display character.